# Apache Spark: Python function serialized automatically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was going through the Apache spark documentation. [Spark docs for python](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) says the following:

> ...We can pass Python functions to Spark, which are automatically
>   serialized along with any variables that they reference...

I don't fully understand what it means. Does it have to do something the the RDD type?

What does it mean in the context of spark?

Answer (score 2):

The [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is necessary when using PySpark because the function you define locally needs to be executed remotely on each of the worker nodes. This concept isn't really related to the RDD type.